# bootstrap column fixed and starts after scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap, i want create site witch will have 3 col like this site: because.tv https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQiIJ.png.

```
>                       <div class="col-lg-5">.col-lg-5</div>
>                       <div class="col-lg-5">.col-lg-5</div>
>                       <div class="col-lg-2">.col-lg-2</div>
```

But i have one problem
How can  create scroll fix like this: if you open site and scroll down column 1 is scrolling after small scroll down column 2 start scroll to and then column 3. how can  i do same ?

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 , canvas framework

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d
translate3d(tx, ty, tz) I think the oaram changes in each column to give that effect

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: You need to use a 3rd party plugin like the "affix" plugin, [for example](https://www.codeply.com/go/wZkBMPg9ST).  But, this question is too broad for stackoverflow.